# How to Sort JSON Products with PHP

Tags: php, json, sorting

How would I sort these two products by say `id:17 value:###` ?

```
{"id":"16","value":"L-AOC000"},
{"id":"17","value":"6.00"},
{"id":"18","value":"10.00"},
{"id":"19","value":"7.52"},
{"id":"20","value":"4.75"},
{"id":"21","value":"3.50"}

{"id":"16","value":"L-AOC001"},
{"id":"17","value":"7.00"},
{"id":"18","value":"11.00"},
{"id":"19","value":"6.52"},
{"id":"20","value":"5.75"},
{"id":"21","value":"4.50"}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the json object to a php array with [json_decode()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). From there, you can use any of the [array sorting functions native to php](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

Well first, you'd want to conver the Json into a php type.

$data = json_decode($the_json_string);

Then what you have is really an array of objects.

You can use **usort**() to sort it out (https://www.php.net/usort) by property.

Seems like you want to test by id first then by value...

```
function sort_by_id_then_value($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->id == $b->id) {
        if ($a->value == $b->value) {
            return 0;
        return ($a->value < $b->value ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a->id < $b->id) ? -1 : 1;
}
  
usort($data, "sort_by_id_then_value");
```